# Tag synonym request: [vlc] -> [vlc-player]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[vlc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vlc) and [vlc-player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vlc-player) seems like they should be synonyms, not entirely sure which way round though!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[vlc-player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vlc-player) just became a synonym of [vlc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vlc).